# How to disable single combobox item in Codename One?

Tags: combobox, codenameone

I went through API and docs and haven't found a way to disable single item in ComboBox. Is there any way to do this or it's unsupported feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an item appear disabled but handling the action (or really not handling it) is up to you.

You can override the renderer to make the combo box appear like anything you want.